# Re-run JavasScript <script> code without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I've got a div which reloads on click using the jQuery [`.load()`][1] method. I also have a `<script>` which obviously contains a jQuery script. The div is dependent on the script to display properly and so I need the script to run again everything the `.load()` function is called on the div.

Comment: Have you tried to just run the `ajaxCart.init({...});` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery load can take a second parameter that is a function to be called when the load is complete. So you can call the function that initializes your div when the load is completed. View the [JQuery API Docs for load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) for more info.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('.cart-container-toggle').on('click', function() {
           $('.cart-container').load("https://www.website.com/ .inner-container", initCartDiv);
            });
        });
</script>

<script>
    function initCartDiv() {
          jQuery(function($) {
            ajaxCart.init({
              formSelector: '#AddToCartForm',
              cartContainer: '#CartContainer',
              addToCartSelector: '#AddToCart',
              cartCountSelector: '#CartCount',
              cartCostSelector: '#CartCost',
              moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }}
            });
          });

          jQuery(document.body).on('afterCartLoad.ajaxCart', function(evt, cart) {
            // Bind to 'afterCartLoad.ajaxCart' to run any javascript after the cart has loaded in the DOM
            timber.RightDrawer.open();
          });
    }

    initCartDiv();
</script>
```